# How can i make a TableRowShorter between two Date

Tags: java, swing, sorting, date, combobox

```
combobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                if(arg0.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    if(!combobox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(items[0])) { //items[] for the items of the combobox.
                        DefaultTableModel table1 = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                        String search =combobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table1);
                        table.setRowSorter(tr);
                        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I use this code. When I select an item of the combobox, it does sort the table with selected item. I have a second combobox. Let's say combobox's name is combobox2 and item of combobox2 is "Last 2 Month".

The first column of the table is for dates. When I select  the item of combobox2 (Last 2 Month), i want to sort the table. I just want to see rows with maximum 2 months old.

For example if I sent the String ("01/01/2020"), I only want to see the rows with ("01/01/2020") and after this date.

But with this code i only can see the date I send. I hope I explained it well. I can share more code if you guys need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example if I sent the String ("01/01/2020"), I only want to see the rows with ("01/01/2020") and after this date.

You need to use a "date filter".

For example this filter will return all the date after a specific date:

```
RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, new Date());
```

Read the `RowFilter` API for other filters you can use.

Note:

You should NOT be storing String values in the model. You should store the date in an object that represents a date and then use a custom renderer to format the date. This will allow the filter from above to work properly.

Comment: The code works fine if i make the dates as this (Sat Aug 15 00:00:00 TRT 2020). But it looks bad. I need the date as (01.08.2020) this. And if i convert it, i can't sort the table.

Comment: As I suggested you need to use a custom renderer to format the Date the way you want it displayed. See [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/).

Comment: Thanks alot. I did not know that so i did not understand what you mean at the first time.

Comment: Is there any way we can avoid having to use the poorly designed and long outdated `java.util.Date` class? Also the modern `LocalDate` seems to fit the OP’s requirements much better and more naturally.